# Evaluate these limits by relating them to a derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives

Evaluate these limits by relating them to a derivative.

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{\cos{x}}-1}{x}$

Comment: Apply l'Hopital

Comment: "Evaluate these limits by relating them to a definition of derivative"

Comment: Also, etiquette would have you actually *ask* politely for help, with some indication of what you have tried, rather than using an imperative as you have.

Comment: What do you mean by "Evaluate these limits by relating them to a derivative" ? Please specify.

Comment: Does this mean you aren't allowed to use l'Hopital? Are you supposed to recognize this as the limit of a difference quotient?

Comment: without l'hospital , assimilate to definition of derivative.

Comment: What is the definition of $\sqrt{\cos(0)}'$?

Comment: yes like that @MPW

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Put $f(t) = \sqrt{\cos t}$, note that $f(0)=1$ and $f(0+x) = f(x) = \sqrt{\cos x}$, and $$\frac{f(0+x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{\cos x} - 1}{x}$$

Can you take it from here?

**Note:** You may recognize the form on the left side of the last line better if you write $h$ (or$\Delta x$) instead of $x$.

Comment: Note I corrected a couple of typos. I think it's correct now.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: rewrite it in the form
$$\frac{(\sqrt{\cos x}-1)(\sqrt{\cos x}+1)}{x(\sqrt{\cos x}+1)(\sqrt{\cos x}+1)}$$